# how can i make custom grid lines to act as guides in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, grids, guides

I want custom angle grid lines.

i learned that i can make them act as guidelines,
but how can i have grid lines other than vertical and horizontal gird lines ?

Comment: What are "custom-angel-grid lines"?  Can you show an example so that we can see what you are hoping to implement in Illustrator?

Comment: I corrected "angel" to "angle" -- if you *really* meant "angel" I'm afraid you'll need to edit and explain what an "angel grid" is.

Comment: I didn't even think about angel/angle.  Good catch, Scott.

Comment: hehe sorry for the bad spellings, is my question more clear now ?

Answer (score 2):

If you mean you want to rotate the **Grid** in Illustrator, as in `View > Show Grid`, see Joojaa's answer - change the preferences for the Constrain Angle.

You can create **guides** at any angle though.,,,

Draw a rectangle the size of the overall grid you want....

With the rectangle selected, choose `Object > Path > Split Into Grid` and define the divisions you desire.

[image]

Double-click the **Rotate Tool** in the **Toolbar** and input the angle you want. Click OK

[image]

Choose `View > Guides > Make Guides` and the paths will be converted to guides.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

1. make guides. Any line can act as a guide line, which is a bit like a grid line although you wont be able to grid snap to them
2. Rotate the grid, you can find this in the **Preferences → general → Constrain angle**

Comment: where is #2?? Have I missed it all these years?

Comment: @Scott updated answer with more precise info. BTW i though you knew everything ;)

Comment: Ahh.. thanks. Yup I wasn't thinking of that at all :) But it does work. And well...I know *nothing*, absolutely nothing. ( especially if I don't use a feature all that much like grids).

Comment: @Scott yeah you are on the 3 level of knowledge i see.